# Why does the console return a first random number before the loops when I run this code?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
for(let i = 0; i< 3; i++){ 
  setTimeout(function (){
    console.log(i)
  }, 200);
}
```

The above code first returns a random number each time I run it in the console before returning `0 1 2`.

Why does it happen like that?

Comment: The setTimeout() returns a timeoutID which identifies the timer created.

Comment: @HosseinMousavi Your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28270850) suggestion is invalid - Remove it and don't change the original code next time please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you post that code to the console in the developer tools on the browser, it evaluates it and outputs whatever it returns. And [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns the timeout id, which can be used to abort it with [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) for example. Of course, the code also runs, and executes as expected, which results in the other outputs.

Comment: But why does the `for` loop evaluate to the last timeout id? The first 2 timeout ids are not displayed on the console

Comment: @adiga for evaluates to whatever the last statement, of the last iteration, inside of it evaluates to.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the for loop that's returning a value. It's setTimeout.

When you write setTimeout it returns a Number, representing the ID value of the timer that is set. You can use this value with the clearTimeout() method to cancel the timer

```
let timer = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Here")
}, 200)


clearTimeout(timer)
```

In your example, if you add the return value to the array you can see all the ids

```
let timers = []
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    timers.push(setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Here", i)
    }, 200))
}

console.log(timers)
```